# "Offer an opinion" or "give an opinion"

Tags: word-choice, differences, verbs, word-usage

Our company is about to relocate. Employees have been asked for input on the new campus. My thought was to preface my email with

> I would like to offer my opinion ...

but should it be

> I would like to give my opinion ...

instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While *give* would be quite acceptable, between the two words, I would choose *offer*. Not only is it a good solid businesslike word, it is also slightly less demanding, and makes you seem less importunate and more polite.

Comment: Agreed. _Offer_ adds a splash of negative [Politeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politeness) to balance the positive.

Answer (score 7):

May I suggest **express**?

> I would like to express my opinion...

Answer (score 5):

Agreed with Daniel (+1) - The difference between the two is *offer* is more polite insofar as it implies the recipient's right to refuse it, whereas *give* implies your insistence that the recipient accept your opinion.  If the rest of your response is very strongly worded, then *give* would be an appropriate choice as it will match the tone of your strongly held opinions.

Comment: @JoelBrown Touché.

Answer (score 2):

There is a single verb meaning "to state an opinion" - **opine**.

> I would like to opine about...